# Find limit as $y\to \infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

> Find the limit of $$\frac{-(iy - 1/2) -|iy-1/2|}{(iy - 1/2) -|iy-1/2|}$$ as $y\to \infty$.

The answer is $i$ but I dont know how to show step by step.

if i divide by y on top and bottom, I get

$$\frac{-i -\frac{|iy-1/2|}{y}}{i -\frac{|iy-1/2|}{y}}$$

The limit of |iy-1/2|/y is 1, but i am not so sure how to get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Divide top and bottom by $y$.

**Added:** To find the limit of $\dfrac{|iy-1/2|}{y}$, note that $|iy-1/2|=\sqrt{y^2+1/4}$. So we are interested in $\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{y^2+1/4}}{y}$. Divide top and bottom by $y$, thus dividing the thing inside the square root by $y^2$. The limit is $1$. (This is geometrically clear: for large positive $y$, the norm of $iy-1/2$ is essentially equal to $y$.)

So our limit is $\dfrac{-i-1}{i-1}$. One can simplify this by changing signs for clarity, then multiplying top and bottom by $1+i$.

Comment: then what do we do with |iy-1/2|/y?

Comment: take the absolute value of iy-1/2 and there is a rule for how to take the absolute value of a complex number, think about the Pythagorean Theorem. When you retake the limit, it can be easily verified that the limit is 1, as you suggested (Calculus 1 problem)

Answer (score 1):

To answer imranfat's question:

$\frac{-i-1}{i-1}
=\frac{-i-1}{i-1}\frac{-i-1}{-i-1}
=\frac{(-i-1)(-i-1)}{(i-1)(-i-1)}
=\frac{-1+2i+1}{2}
=\frac{2i}{2}
= i
$

I found that I had to be $very$ careful
taking the conjugate of $i-1$
and doing the multiplications.